# Can't seem to figure out how to get the output of an process fired with spawn. stdout.on('data') not outputting for me

Tags: node.js, typescript, windows, stdout, spawn

I am trying to setup some automation on a [game server](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Rust_Dedicated_Server) for the game [Rust](https://store.steampowered.com/app/252490/Rust/).
The game server itself is ran by running its executable file RustDedicated.exe [with some arguments.](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Rust_Dedicated_Server#Configuration_.26_running)

According to some googling and reading here on Stack Overflow I have made this script:

```
import config from "config";
import { ChildProcessWithoutNullStreams, spawn } from "child_process";

const GAMESERVERPATH: string =  config.get("Environment.RustDedicatedPath");
const EXECUTABLE: string =      config.get("Environment.ExecutableFile");
const GAMESERVERARGS: Array<string> = [
    "-batchmode",
    "+server.port",         `${config.get("Server.port")}`,
    "+server.level",        `"${config.get("Server.level")}"`,
    "+server.seed",         `${config.get("Server.seed")}`,
    "+server.worldsize",    `${config.get("Server.worldsize")}`,
    "+server.maxplayers",   `${config.get("Server.maxplayers")}`,
    "+server.hostname",     `"${config.get("Server.hostname")}"`,
    "+server.description",  `"${config.get("Server.description")}"`,
    "+server.headerimage",  `"${config.get("Server.headerimage")}"`,
    "+rcon.port",           `${config.get("Rcon.port")}`,
    "+rcon.password",       `"${config.get("Rcon.password")}"`,
    "+rcon.web",            `${config.get("Rcon.web")}`
];

const gameServerProc : ChildProcessWithoutNullStreams = spawn(
    GAMESERVERPATH+EXECUTABLE,
    GAMESERVERARGS,
    {
        cwd:            GAMESERVERPATH,
        shell:          true,
    }
);

gameServerProc.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
    console.log(`stdout:${data.toString()}`);
});
gameServerProc.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
    console.log(`stderr:${data.toString()}`);
});
gameServerProc.on("error", (err) => {
    console.log(`error:${err.message}`);
});
```

What is happening is that i can see the output of the executable in the terminal window, and the server is firing without errors, but it seems that stdout is not firing the on('data') event.
I never see `stdout:`.

See the screenshot below where i have Code open, the output is on the bottom right.
[image: Dump of Code]

Why is my script failing to get the on('data') firing when the executable outputs?

Answer (score 0):

This issue had nothing to do with the code, but rather the game engine Unity. An extra argument `-logFile -` had to be present for the executable to output to stdout.